How to run kaniko inside a container without k8s in jenkins?
I have a public repository which contains an Angular-App and i tried to build a CI/CD pipeline using jenkins for this app. You can find the full code of .jenkinsfile file in this link.
As you can see, i have a stage for building and pushing the image of app in a container registery in azure using the below code:
stage('Build Image/Push') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([
                    string(credentialsId: 'AZURE_TENANT_ID', variable: 'AZURE_TENANT_ID'),
                    string(credentialsId: 'AZURE_CLIENT_ID', variable: 'AZURE_CLIENT_ID'),
                    string(credentialsId: 'AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET', variable: 'AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET')
                ]) {
                    sh 'az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID'
                    sh 'az acr login --name salmanprivatedockerregistery --expose-token'

                    // Using Kaniko to build and push the Docker image
                    
                    sh """
                     kaniko-executor --context ${BUILD_CONTEXT} --dockerfile ${DOCKERFILE} \
                                    --destination ${IMAGE}:latest \
                                    --azure-container-registry-config ${DOCKER_CONFIG}/acr_cred.json
                     """
                }
            }

In this step, i use my stored secrets to cominuicate with Azure and it goes well successfully. However when it comes to runnign the  kaniko-executor command it fails with the below error:
+ kaniko-executor --context /var/jenkins_home/workspace/marvel-pipeline --dockerfile /var/jenkins_home/workspace/marvel-pipeline/Dockerfile --destination salmanprivatedockerregistery.azurecr.io/marvel-app:latest --azure-container-registry-config /var/jenkins_home/workspace/marvel-pipeline/.docker/acr_cred.json
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/marvel-pipeline@tmp/durable-3326cae1/script.sh.copy: 2: kaniko-executor: not found

Please notice all the needed parameters for this command is set in the jenkins as below:
 environment {
        CHROME_BIN = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
        DOCKER_CONFIG = "${env.WORKSPACE}/.docker"
        IMAGE = 'salmanprivatedockerregistery.azurecr.io/marvel-app'
        KANIKO_IMAGE = 'gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest'
        // Define Dockerfile path if different from root
        DOCKERFILE = "${env.WORKSPACE}/Dockerfile"
        // Define build context if different from root (use '.' for root)
        BUILD_CONTEXT = "${env.WORKSPACE}"
    }

I understand that kaniko-executor: not found means the kaniko is not found in the path, but i don't know why and how i can fix it ?!

you replace cammand kaniko-executor  with command  /kaniko/executor
for example :
sh "/kaniko/executor --cache=true --dockerfile $DOCKERFILE --context $CONTEXT --destination ${image} --verbosity debug"
